# Use a program identifier in a syntax extension

Tags: macros, rust

In a Rust syntax extension, how could I use an identifier from the program's scope?

For instance, let's say I have the following code:

```
fn test() {
    let name = "test";
    let result = my_macro!();
}
```

I tried to define the procedural macro as following:

```
fn expand_my_macro(cx: &mut ExtCtxt, sp: Span, args: &[TokenTree]) -> Box<MacResult + 'static> {
    MacEager::expr(cx.expr_ident(sp, Ident::with_empty_ctxt(intern("name"))))
}
```

But, I get the following error:

```
error: unresolved name `name` [E0425]
```

in the user code.

I know that normal Rust macro are hygienic, but what about procedural macro?

Is there a way to do this without having to pass the variable `name` as an argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe so.  The problem is that in order for you to match the existing `name` identifier, you *need* to know its syntax context: identifier equality compares both the textual name *and* the syntax context exactly.

This is a problem because you are not told, and have no way of knowing, what the surrounding syntax context *is*.

If you want to refer to it, you *have* to pass the identifier into the macro.

Comment: I believe it should be possible since there is a `concat_idents` macro in `syntax::ext` which creates a new identifier. I tried to do the same thing as the code from this macro, but I get the same error.

Comment: @antoyo: There is a difference between referring to an external identifier and creating a new one; for one thing, in the latter case, you know that the created identifier should be injected in the syntactical scope of the macro.

Answer (score 0):

As I send other identifiers as parameters to the macro, I was able to use an external identifier.

I needed to get the `SyntaxContext` from the call site:

```
fn expand_my_macro(cx: &mut ExtCtxt, sp: Span, args: &[TokenTree]) -> Box<MacResult + 'static> {
    if let TokenTree::TtToken(_, Token::Ident(ident, _)) = args[0] {
        let name_ident = Ident::new(intern("name"), ident.ctxt);
        MacEager::expr(cx.expr_ident(sp, name_ident)))
    }
    DummyResult::any(sp)
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
fn test() {
    let name = "test";
    let result = my_macro!(foo);
}
```